# How to provide the sort order in a variable in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by

Right now what I am doing is as :

```
if order_type == 'desc':
    result = session.\
             query(Customer).\
             order_by(desc(getattr(Customer, sorting_column_name))).\
             all()
else:
    result = session.\
             query(Customer).\
             order_by(asc(getattr(Customer, sorting_column_name))).\
             all()
```

Is there any way to call `order_by` just once and use sorting order provided in `order_type` as a variable to decide whether to sort `asc` or `desc`?

Answer (score 9):

[`asc`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.asc) and [`desc`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.desc) are just objects, pick one based on the ordering you want:

```
direction = desc if order_type == 'desc' else asc

result = session.\
         query(Customer).\
         order_by(direction(getattr(Customer, sorting_column_name))).\
         all()
```

`direction` is bound to either `asc` or `desc` depending on the value of `order_type`, then used in building the query.